# Machine Learning: How to handle discrete and continuous data together

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification

I'm posting to ask whether there any methodologies, or ideas as to how to handle discrete and continuous data in a classifying problem.

In my situation, I have a bunch of independent "batches" that have discrete data. This is process related data, and so for each batch, there are separate points. I also have a dataset, that varies with time for the same batches. This time however there are many time observations for every batch. The data sets look like below:

```
Data Set 1

Batch 1      DiscreteInfo(1)      DiscreteInfo(2) ....... DiscreteInfo(n)
Batch 2      DiscreteInfo(1)      DiscreteInfo(2) ....... DiscreteInfo(n)
Batch 3      DiscreteInfo(1)      DiscreteInfo(2) ....... DiscreteInfo(n)
Batch 4      DiscreteInfo(1)      DiscreteInfo(2) ....... DiscreteInfo(n)

Data Set 2

Batch 1      t(1)      TimeData
Batch 1      t(2)      TimeData 
Batch 1      t(3)      TimeData
Batch 1      t(4)      TimeData
.
.
.
.
Batch n     (t1)      TimeData
Batch n     (t2)      TimeData
Batch n     (t3)      TimeData
```

I am trying to classify whether all this data belongs to a 'Good' batch, a 'Bad' batch, or a 'so-so' batch. This is determined by one specific discrete parameter (not used in the data sets).

I'm very new to machine learning; any input or ideas would be appreciated. I'm using the matlab classification learner to try to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you need to consider while dealing with a classification problem.

1. Training Data. We need training data for classification, i-e we need all the above mentioned attribute's values along with the class value whether it is 'Good' or 'Bad' or 'so-so'.
2. Using this we can train a model, and then given a new data for all the trained attributes we can predict which class it belongs to.

As far as discrete and continuous is concerned, There is no difference in the way we handle discrete and continuous data. In fact, for this case we can generate a new attribute which will be a function of all the other time variables for a given batch and then perform the classification. If you provide an instance of the data-set then the question can be answered more precisely.

Comment: The data is structured like in my question. I can't really give an example dataset, because I don't think I'm allowed to share the information.

Essentially, we have two tables of data. One is a discrete table that includes the class value and various other discrete information (usually stuff that's written in process and only once per batch). In another data table, we have all the time varying data belonging to each batch (about 1300 rows of information per batch; this is stuff like temperature at time t.

Comment: If you think that the temperature data is an essential information to help classifying then you have to design a new column for each batch which will be a derived column from all these 1300 rows of information. For example mean, variance,  skewness, Kurtosis etc. Using these variables now the data is in one table and now you can use any standard Machine Learning Algorithms. Hope this helps